# Добавить исключение в регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть задача изменять значение поля input (автоматически делать заглавную букву в начале нового предложения - "чтоб как в word" ) почти получилось при помощи следующей функции

```js
  function(){
    inputPos = this.selectionStart;
    this.value = this.value.replace(/((?:(?:^|[.?!]\s)\s*))(.)/g, 
    function(m, tail, ch){return tail + ch.toUpperCase()})
      this.selectionStart = inputPos; 
      this.selectionEnd = inputPos;
  }
```

подскажите, как добавить исключение в регулярку, чтобы игнорировались слова длиной в 1 символ (т.к. т.ч. т.е.) и после них буква в слове оставалась строчной

Пример ввода:

> "любой текст. меняется по onclick в инпуте! текст произвольный, но
>   нужно игнорировать сокращения т.е. слова длиной в один символ
>   заканчивающиеся точкой т.к. такова идея. очень лень шифт нажимать...
>   ну не дичь ли? вот так"

Пример Вывода:

> "Любой текст. Меняется по onclick в инпуте! Текст произвольный, но
>   нужно игнорировать сокращения т.е. слова длиной в один символ
>   заканчивающиеся точкой т.к. такова идея. Очень лень шифт нажимать...
>   Ну не дичь ли? Вот так"

Comment: А почему бы простое условие не сделать? Или именно в регулярке надо?

Comment: нет способ не принципиален. Задача - эмулировать поведение ms word (делать большие буквы в начале предложения) при вводе текста юзером в инпуте исключая "т.к.","т.ч.","т.п.","т.д."...Мне регулярка показалась самым логичным решением

Comment: дай пример входной и исходной строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я пока лучше ничего не придумал, но вроде работает:

```
/(?<=(^|([а-я]{2,})[!?.]{1,}\s))./
```

Подробности:

- `(?<=` - начало предпросматриваемой незахватывающей группы

  - `(^|([а-я]{2,})` - условие, по которому мы избавляемся от таких сокращенных слов `т.е.`, `т.к.` и прочих таких сокращений, где стоит меньше 2 символов `а-я`
  - `[!?.]{1,}` - свои спец. символ, по которым осуществляем поиск в пределах от 1+
- `)` - конец предпросматриваемой группы
- `.` - выбираем первую нужную нам букву

```js
var string = 'любой текст. меняется по onclick в инпуте!!! ' +
'текст произвольный... нужно игнорировать сокращения т.е. слова ' +
'длиной в один символ заканчивающиеся точкой т.к. такова идея. ' + 
'очень лень шифт нажимать... ну не дичь ли!? вот так';

var value = string.replace(/(?<=(^|([а-я]{2,})[!?.]{1,}\s))./gi, function(ch) {
    return ch.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(value);
```

Comment: Спасибо! поставленную задачу решило. Не сработало только на множественных восклицательных знаках и ?! но этого не было в исходной задаче.

Comment: Дайте пример строки, где используется много знаков таких

Comment: немного изменил исходную => "любой текст. меняется по onclick в инпуте!!! текст произвольный... нужно игнорировать сокращения т.е. слова длиной в один символ заканчивающиеся точкой т.к. такова идея. очень лень шифт нажимать... ну не дичь ли!? вот так"

Comment: обновил решение